# How to structure correctly a Symfony2 controller - deal with huge classes

Tags: php, symfony, bundle

I have an existing PHP project that I have to move on Symfony.
I am working with symfony for 6 month and found it very nice to use.

Hovewer, I have a question:

In the old code, I have some big classes of about 6000 each :|
Now, In the new project, I have My controller where everything should be done (including 2 or 3 classes of 6000 lines).

What is the **best practcice with symfony**, creating another bundle per huge class and call the functions of 2 or 3 bundles in the controller, or something else?

Comment: I know that a class of 6000 lines is a very bad practice, but I am working on an existing code, so I will have to deal with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read up on Symfony more and the answers may just fall into place, especially Services http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html

**EDIT**

Look at the code and divide it up logically. I have no idea what the controller does, but it could well be valid as one class - but that is unlikely. Look at the class and make decisions about how best to split it up.

Do this as a diagram or on paper first! Doing it in code first takes much much longer and is harder to fix when you inevitably make a mistake the first time around.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion. I know the Symfony2 services. So, your idea will be to use services. But, A service per huge class, so at hte endm having a couple of services, or even those huge class, to divide them into smaller services and at the end have 10, 20 or 30 seervices.

Comment: Thanks again @jakenoble. In fact, The code can surely be divided into smaller peaces of code. As I mentioned, there are some huge classes that are doing everything, all of them have 5 and more methods inside. So, the eventual idea will be to split those classes in several small ones and then create a service per small class.

Comment: And another thing: Should I create all those services in the same bundle or divide them in multiple bundles?

Comment: It depends on if they'd be useful as individual components for other projects in the future.

Comment: Probably not, the code will be used locally for the moment. So, Better having everything in the same bundle, right? And another question (sorry for bothering you), where should be put all those service classes?